# Is jQuery parsing the data before it is output?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have been having a lot of problems with section of code, just as I thought it was all working great I find there is a new problem. It is part of a chat script and this section outputs the final code to div /div but the output is not what is expected. I am trying to implement a button where when it is pressed it will prompt a user to enter a valid youtube video URL, it is then sent to the Node.js server and then sent back to the browser. When I console.log the incoming data to the browser, it is what I was expecting.
The problem is After the data is sent to the function myChat(bubble), the youtube link and div contents look as though they have already been parsed and displays just a white box where the video should be.
I have shortened the code below removing code which is not needed for an example.

```
sock.onmessage = function(event){
    var json = JSON.parse(event.data);
    
    const key = json.name;
    if(key) {
        if (key === "Server"){
        
            var bubble = '<div class="bubble-container"><span class="server"><div class="bubble-text"><p><strong>&lt;'+json.name+'&gt;</strong> '+json.data+'</p></div></div>';
            
        }else{
        
            const zKey = json.lock;
            var bubble = $('<div class="bubble-container" id="'+json.name+'"><span class="bubble"><div class="bubble-text" id="'+zKey+'"><p><div class="close-x" onclick="DelBubble(event, urank)"></div><strong> &lt;'+json.name+'&gt;</strong> '+string+'</p></div></div>');
    
        }
    myChat(bubble);
    }   
}
    
function myChat(bubble){

    $("#msgText").val("");
    $(".bubble-container:last").after(bubble);
    if (bubbles >= maxBubbles) {
        var first = $(".bubble-container:first").remove();
        bubbles--;
    }

    bubbles++;
    $('.bubble-container').show(250, function showNext() {
        if (!($(this).is(":visible"))) {
            bubbles++;
        }

        $(this).next(".bubble-container").show(250, showNext);
        $("#wrapper1").scrollTop(9999999);
    });     
};
```

I have tried everything I can think of and have now run out of ideas. All I want is the string to output the same as it was entered by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- You use `var` in a very confusing and bad way. Use `let` instead.
- Your `bubble` var is one time filled with a string and another time with a jQuery element
- Your `bubble` content strings have an unequal amount of opening and closing tags. Check your HTML
- We can't comment on things we can not see, like `#msgText`, either include them or exclude them completely
- Your code probably does not work because of some mistake in the areas we cant comment on. Check my snippet to see that it works

```js
const bubble = `<div class="bubble">
                  <strong>&lt;${'TEST'}&gt;</strong>
                  ${'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0'}
              </div>`;

$(".bubble:last").after(bubble);
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.bubble {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <div class="bubble">
    <strong>&lt;USER1&gt;</strong>Message text
  </div>
</div>
```

As you requested a solution to show the video directly in the chat, here is a message with an embeded video player:

```js
const embedMessage = (user, message) => {
  let bubble;
  
  if(message.includes('https://www.youtube.com')) {
    bubble = `<div class="bubble">
                  <strong>&lt;${user}&gt;</strong>
                  <iframe width="200" height="100"
src="${message}"></iframe>
              </div>`;
  } else {
    bubble = `<div class="bubble">
                  <strong>&lt;${user}&gt;</strong>
                  ${message}
              </div>`;
  }
  
  $(".bubble:last").after(bubble);
}


embedMessage('USER1', 'Send me the video!');
embedMessage('USER2', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0');
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.bubble {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <div class="bubble">
    <strong>&lt;USER1&gt;</strong>Message text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea how to implement that code in to mine, I will have a play about with it and see what I can do. the code snippet works on here but does not show any video content, just one line with <USER1>Message text and another line with <TEST> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0. I have not been using jQuery or javascript for long, only 4 weeks.

Comment: It is your code, just cut to the significant parts because the rest does not fully exist in your snippet, so we can't comment on that. Yes it shows only the URL...why should it show anything else? If you want to show a playable video, you have to implement a video player....

Comment: I have added some code to embed the video play @CharlyWilly

Comment: yes, it is my code mostly, it is also meant to show the video player. when the person clicks on the youtube button they are prompted for a youtube video URL, when they enter it the browser wraps the <iframe data around the URL and then sends it to the server. The server then does it's checks and then sends the iframe code back to everyone in chat. Everything works fine apart from the final output which is just a white box. I will try and get something more practical and easier to work with posted here soon. thanks

Comment: Don't send an iframe around the message to the server! Wrap it around it in the receiving part. You don't want to process HTML on the server, you want to process raw messages. Your mistake is still outside of the given code as shown by my second code snippet @CharlyWilly

Comment: what is sent to the server is [iframe, the server does a search and replaces < with [ and replaces [/iframe] with </iframe] etc

Comment: That is a very overcomplicated and bad approach to this problem. You are sending invalid data to the server and sending half-invalid data back. Why would you think that the browser understands `</iframe]`? Have you ever seen an "]" in HTML code? Also, you are opening up your whole application for XSS Attacks which is really REALLY bad. Please don't try this any further, or your application is a fail from the get-go. @CharlyWilly Just send the raw URL to the server and let the client handle it however you want.

Comment: ok, I will spend a few hours looking through everything and try making the corrections you suggested, I am as fast at this as you :) I will pop back a bit later and let you know how I got on

Comment: Do that, but please post a new question on SO for the follow-up problems and close this one by accepting my answer if your current question got answered. @CharlyWilly

Comment: when the tags [ ]  are sent back to the browser they are already converted to < > by the server. I have created a pastbin of the entire server as it is at present, I removed most of the smileys as they just took up space and left 1 or 2. I don't pretend to be a pro because I am not, 4 weeks ago I had never seen jQuery before. I will mark your post as the answer even though I have not had time to look at it fully. This is my first attempt at creating anything using jQuery or javascript. here is the pastebin https://pastebin.com/Hf911m2Z thanks

Comment: It is still not a good idea. Think about this - what if someone sends you the message `[script]alert('hi')[/script]`. That would be a harmless example. Please look at my second snippet and do it like I did it - it is the simplest solution and probably one of the better ones. Cant look at your pastebin right now, but I suggest you to open a new post on SO with your new question. @CharlyWilly